Crash UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency adding a root view controller UISplitViewController as a child of view controller UISplitViewController
App seems to be crashing in UIKit when it is running on iPad.
Has anyone experienced this crash. Here is crash report. Not able to reproduce consistently.
adding a root view controller <UISplitViewController: 0x10b527030> as a child of view controller:<UISplitViewController: 0x10b527030>
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x32dd56684         __exceptionPreprocess
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31e1f2190         objc_exception_throw
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32de4a6a8         +[NSException raise:format:]
3   UIKitCore                       0x3321e3cf8         -[UIViewController _addChildViewController:]
4   UIKitCore                       0x3321e36fc         -[UIViewController _addChildViewController:performHierarchyCheck:notifyWillMove:]
5   UIKitCore                       0x3323a2e40         -[UISplitViewController addChildViewController:]
6   UIKitCore                       0x3323a2a5c         -[UIPanelController _addIdentifiedChildViewController:]
7   UIKitCore                       0x332488c7c         __56-[UIPanelController _collapseWithTransitionCoordinator:]_block_invoke_4
8   UIKitCore                       0x332488a84         +[UIPanelController _withDisabledAppearanceTransitions:forVisibleDescendantsOf:perform:]
9   UIKitCore                       0x332488750         -[UIPanelController _withDisabledAppearanceTransitionsPerform:]
10  UIKitCore                       0x3324886b0         __56-[UIPanelController _collapseWithTransitionCoordinator:]_block_invoke_3
11  UIKitCore                       0x332357dcc         +[UIViewController _performWithoutDeferringTransitionsAllowingAnimation:actions:]
12  UIKitCore                       0x33205a104         __56-[UIPanelController _collapseWithTransitionCoordinator:]_block_invoke_2
13  UIKitCore                       0x332057810         +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:]
14  UIKitCore                       0x3323c0714         __56-[UIPanelController _collapseWithTransitionCoordinator:]_block_invoke
15  UIKitCore                       0x3322b18bc         -[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator _applyBlocks:releaseBlocks:]
16  UIKitCore                       0x3322b17b4         -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext __runAlongsideAnimations]
17  UIKitCore                       0x332840498         -[_UIWindowAnimationController animateTransition:]
18  UIKitCore                       0x3324dd8ac         -[UIWindow _adjustSizeClassesAndResizeWindowToFrame:]
19  UIKitCore                       0x3321465a4         -[UIWindow _resizeWindowFrameToSceneBoundsIfNecessary]
20  UIKitCore                       0x332145aa4         -[UIWindow _sceneBoundsDidChange]
21  UIKitCore                       0x33232b470         -[_UIScenefbsSceneBasedMetricsCalculator _updateMetricsOnWindows:animated:]
22  UIKitCore                       0x33232b0b0         -[UIWindowScene _computeMetricsForWindows:animated:]
23  UIKitCore                       0x3321a5d7c         __55-[UIWindowScene _computeMetrics:withTransitionContext:]_block_invoke
24  UIKitCore                       0x3323d3b84         -[UIWindowScene _computeTraitCollectionAndCoordinateSpaceForcingDelegateCallback:withAction:]
25  UIKitCore                       0x3323d448c         -[UIWindowScene _computeMetrics:withTransitionContext:]
26  UIKitCore                       0x3325f2d70         ___UIWindowHostingScenePerformUpdateWithEffectiveSettings_block_invoke_2
27  UIKitCore                       0x332357dcc         +[UIViewController _performWithoutDeferringTransitionsAllowingAnimation:actions:]
28  UIKitCore                       0x3325f2cf8         ___UIWindowHostingScenePerformUpdateWithEffectiveSettings_block_invoke
29  UIKitCore                       0x332057810         +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:]
30  UIKitCore                       0x3325f1df4         _UIWindowHostingScenePerformUpdateWithEffectiveSettings
31  UIKitCore                       0x3325f1d10         -[UIScene _guardedSetOverrideSettings:]
32  UIKitCore                       0x3325f1f0c         -[UIScene _applyOverrideSettings:forActions:]
33  UIKitCore                       0x332f64e98         -[UIWindowScene _applySnapshotSettings:forActions:]
34  UIKitCore                       0x332d9c8e8         -[UIApplication _createSnapshotContextForScene:withName:performLayoutWithSettings:]
35  UIKitCore                       0x332d9d93c         __65-[UIApplication _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:]_block_invoke_3
36  FrontBoardServices              0x35c734500         -[FBSSceneSnapshotAction _executeNextRequest]
37  FrontBoardServices              0x35c73451c         [inlined] -[FBSSceneSnapshotAction _executeNextRequest]
38  FrontBoardServices              0x35c73451c         -[FBSSceneSnapshotAction _executeNextRequest]
39  FrontBoardServices              0x35c733ff0         -[FBSSceneSnapshotAction executeRequestsWithHandler:completionHandler:expirationHandler:]
40  UIKitCore                       0x332d9d88c         __65-[UIApplication _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:]_block_invoke_2
41  UIKitCore                       0x332d9d1d0         -[UIApplication _beginSnapshotSessionForScene:withSnapshotBlock:]
42  UIKitCore                       0x332d9d778         __65-[UIApplication _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:]_block_invoke
43  UIKitCore                       0x3325f1e58         -[UIScene _enableOverrideSettingsForActions:]
44  UIKitCore                       0x3325f2078         -[UIScene _performSystemSnapshotWithActions:]
45  UIKitCore                       0x332d9d610         -[UIApplication _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:]
46  UIKitCore                       0x3331a518c         __98-[_UISceneSnapshotBSActionsHandler _respondToActions:forFBSScene:inUIScene:fromTransitionContext:]_block_invoke_3
47  UIKitCore                       0x3331a5028         __98-[_UISceneSnapshotBSActionsHandler _respondToActions:forFBSScene:inUIScene:fromTransitionContext:]_block_invoke_2
48  UIKitCore                       0x3321e41a8         -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:]
49  UIKitCore                       0x3322a34b8         -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]
50  UIKitCore                       0x3322a30d0         -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:]
51  FrontBoardServices              0x35c6d814c         -[FBSScene updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:]
52  FrontBoardServices              0x35c6e72dc         __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _queue_updateScene:withSettings:diff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2
53  FrontBoardServices              0x35c6e7194         -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:]
54  FrontBoardServices              0x35c6eb528         __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _queue_updateScene:withSettings:diff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
55  libdispatch.dylib               0x33cb02cbc         _dispatch_client_callout
56  libdispatch.dylib               0x33caa6ea8         _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp
57  FrontBoardServices              0x35c6e86b0         __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
58  FrontBoardServices              0x35c6e8638         -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible]
59  FrontBoardServices              0x35c6e854c         -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource]
60  CoreFoundation                  0x32dd2b120         __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
61  CoreFoundation                  0x32dd2b0b8         __CFRunLoopDoSource0
62  CoreFoundation                  0x32dd28d9c         __CFRunLoopDoSources0
63  CoreFoundation                  0x32dd27f38         __CFRunLoopRun
64  CoreFoundation                  0x32dd277d4         CFRunLoopRunSpecific
65  GraphicsServices                0x3ad1d5810         GSEventRunModal
66  UIKitCore                       0x33239d264         -[UIApplication _run]
67  UIKitCore                       0x332447908         UIApplicationMain
68  SampleApp                       0x202627540         main (main.m:21)
69  <unknown>                       0x1c740b228         <redacted>


I managed to fix the issue. When app goes into the background, iOS calls the delegate method
optional func primaryViewController(forCollapsing splitViewController: UISplitViewController) -> UIViewController?
I was returning the instance of UISplitViewController in this method, hence app crashed. After returning the non UISplitViewController, crash is fixed

Impossible to provide a solution as you haven't included any code, but I suspect the issue is from trying to use a UISplitViewController as a child view controller of another view controller.  UISplitViewController is intended to be a root view controller as stated in the UISplitViewController documentation:

Note
You can’t push a split view controller onto a navigation stack.
Although it’s possible to install a split view controller as a child
in some other container view controllers, doing so isn’t recommended
in most cases. For design guidance, see Split
views.

